# How do I move from app development to device-specific ROM development?

Tags: apk

I've seen a lot of resources on developing Android apps. But there are no guides on how to develop the OS itself. I'm looking at developing ROMs for my specific device. Is it true that the ROM is just a bunch of .apk files strung together?

How do I learn about Android OS development? Do I learn about app development first? And if I do so, how do I move on to developing custom ROMs that are optimised for my device? As of now, I don't see any resources available online. Just some tutorials on compiling from source. Even so, I don't know how to find my device specific "sources" or my device "tree" or my "proprietary binaries". If anyone can shed some light on this issue, and show me what I need to do after I learn Android app development, so that I can move on later to start developing custom ROMs for my device, I would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: "Is it true that the ROM is just a bunch of .apk" no , apk are for dalvik a virtual machine that runs on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly android is not just bunch of apps its a complete OS, just read through the wiki

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)

In learning terms, both are very vast fields...
It will take you at least a year to get proficient in App development / ROM development...

If u want to learn App development there are lot of resources online like
android.com, books like Busy coder's guide to android development etc...
And knowing basics of Java is a must...

Best place to learn ROM development is the xda forums.. There are device specific sub-forums...
But ROM development takes more of a trial n error approach, it will test your patience..
And there is not proper documentation also...

So choose what u want...
I would personally suggest App dev first... :-)

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, I want to learn to develop custom roms.I have a fair knowledge of app development.Now  I want to know which approach to build a rom is better is it [Android Kitchen](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=633246) alone, or is there another way using Eclipse.

Comment: Custom rom development involves lot of stuff. Basically u use Kitchen for all the background works like zipalign, pre - rooting, building your rom. Most of these may sound foreign to u. But ull as u go along. Most of the stuff is done manually. U can learn by following numerous posts in XDA